# find the limits : $\lim_{n}( \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot \cdot \cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6 \cdot \cdot \cdot (2n)} ) =?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the limits (without Stirling's approximation ) :
>
> $$\lim_{n}( \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot \cdot \cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6 \cdot \cdot \cdot (2n)} ) =?$$

---

My Try :

$$\frac{1\times 3\times 5\cdots \times(2n-1)}{2\times 4\times 6\cdots \times(2n)}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$$

now what ?

Comment: Stirling's approximation ???

Comment: Why can't you use stirling's approximation?

Comment: [there's a nice approximation:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) $$\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Comment: Also: the limit as $n$ approaches **what**?? You haven't specified ... maybe $\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

This is
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right).$$
Its logarithm is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right).$$
Does that sum converge/diverge/what?

Answer (score 1):

Use induction to prove that
$\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$. Now, because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ tends to 0, it follows that your limit is 0.

Answer (score -1):

maybe it will help you. the answer in the image is a partial result

[image]

Since the root of k is necessary for it to converge to a value, I must assume that the limit of the production tends to zero, and that its rate of growth is equal to that of the square root of k

Comment: Why write $\frac{\sqrt\pi}\pi$?

Comment: because that is the answer to the limit, if you prefer $\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}$